# Should I handle exceptions in ViewModel or BL?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know I should handle data validation in the View but should the ViewModel handle exceptions or should I make sure my BL handles all exceptions?

My thought process behind this question is that if two ViewModel used the same BL class they would need to duplicate error handling.

Comment: While very opinion based, error handling should be treated as a cross cutting concern to keep the code DRY but there are cases where this can fall into the *it depends* category.

Comment: That is what I was thinking but was also concerned about how I would present and error to the GUI

Comment: look into the mediator pattern

Comment: "I know I should handle data validation in the View" - I wonder how do you write unit tests for BL with invalid input?

Comment: @ASh I would use a `ValidationRule` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationrule?view=netframework-4.7.2